# How to install and use Jupyter lab in a Python virtual environment on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook, virtual-environment

i build up a virtual environment for Python on Linux:

[image]

I install some libraries, which all look fine. Then I try to install Jupyter lab like this:

[image]

......

[image]

I am not good at Linux stuff. So I am not even sure if Jupyterlab is installed or not.

But I just try Jupyter lab in the virtual environment, then I have the following information:

[image]

Looks like lunux automatically allocate Jupyter lab to this path. But because the system just give me very small space under here, so Jupyterlab is actually not installed.

So, how can I install Jupyter lab in the virtual environment?

I am a beginner at Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try: `pip install jupyterlab` within your virtual env, then type `jupyter-lab` to start the server.